# Print multiple copies in same sheet. Crystal Reports. .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, printing, report

Using Crystal Reports and .NET I have a requeriment where I need to print 2 copies of the same report on each sheet. I´m able to do this using two subreports setting CanGrow to false, but this doesnt work cause my report may have more than one page, and CanGrow will just crop the rest of the report. Setting CanGrow to false will cause the two reports to overlap, or print one after another. I also tried making a double report, Header - details - footer, and Header - details - footer again (repeating the same information), but crystal reports doesnt allow me to have multiple details sections(with header footer sections between them).

I´m able to reproduce what I want using MsWord, in the printing settings changing the printer setting "print multiple copies" to 2, and then typing and setting Page range to "Page: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4... " but the printing API from Crystal Reports won´t let me adjust these settings, not even printing APIs from .NET, so I though of using Native Win32 API, but even if I´m able to do this with Win32 I don´t know how to tell Crystal Reports to use my printing functions.

I´m pretty new to crystal reports so maybe there is a simple solution for this. If someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I kind of solved it. I created two reports: Orignal, and Copy, and supressed all sections except details section and added a group using the workaround mentioned here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SubReportPH10062006160749PM/SubReportPH.aspx

to be able to use headers that would repeat on every page.

I put all my header information on the group header, and the report footer information on the group footer(other sections can´t be used since they wont respect the spacing I need, that´s the major drawback of this workaround), and limit the details section to a number of records that will fill only half of the page. In the copy version I added a space in the header equal to half of the page. Then I created the report that will hold both subreports with all sections supressed and only one detail section, and added both subreports there one on top of another. This will print the second subreport at the bottom of the page leaving the space from its header for the first subreport to print on top, I still don´t know how to repeat footing section on every page by now but I think I don´t need it.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to keep your subreport the way you have it, with the report details you want copied, but you can't place the two instances of the subreport in the same section and expect them to space themselves correctly.  You'll need to use a second detail section in your main report for your second subreport, then they shouldn't overwrite each other.  The detail sections both need cangrow = true set.

---

OK, all you should need is 2 reports, one formatted the way the customer wants (headers, footers, etc.) to use as the subreport, and one without any headers or footers, but 2 detail sections with cangrow=true and an instance of the subreport in each detail section.  I'm not sure why you want a new page after 5 records, but try taking that out and see if you can print the same subreport twice within a main report.

Comment: I tried this: I created one report with only a detail section with prints all records.

Comment: (edit)Hi, thank you, I tried this: I created one report "A" with only a detail section which prints all records (set new page after visible records = 5). Then created a new report, added a second detail section and inserted the report "A" as 2 subreports on each detail section. This will print the first subreport good, but the second subreport will just repeat the first 5 records on all pages. I tried others things but this was the closer I could get to what I want.

Comment: Yes, that´s what I have. That works ok if my number of records is less than can fit half of the page, but my report can have multiple pages, if I don´t limit the number of records per page the first report is printed with all its pages, and then the second report prints after. If I limit the number of records, I have the problem I mentioned in the previous post, the top report prints fine on every page the way I want, but the bottom report will just print the first "n" records on every page. n being the number of records to fit half of the page.

Comment: you want them interwoven?  so the top of the first copy prints at the top of the first page, and the top of the second copy prints at the bottom of the first page?  If that's the case, try adjusting the print setup so it thinks the paper is half as tall.